# Get website headline with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to get a website's headline (in Vietnamese) using Nokogiri:

[image]

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://vnexpress.net"))   
list = page.css("a[class='link-topnews']")
puts list[0].text
```

but it's giving the error:

```
undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

The weird thing is, with the exact same code, sometimes it does work and gives the correct result:

```
Triều Tiên dọa hành động với máy bay B-52 của Mỹ
```

Even when trying to get the title it's giving the same error:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://vnexpress.net/"))   
list = page.css("title")
puts list[0].text
```

Why does it behave like that? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the their server refuses to serve content when you use just nokogiri. I suppose, they are checking some headers. You can add headers or use Mechanize gem:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get "http://vnexpress.net"
page.search("a.link-topnews").first.text
```

=> "Triều Tiên dọa hành động với máy bay B-52 của Mỹ"

Comment: thanks, it works. Do you have any idea why they would do that? i.e refusing to serve content when you use just Nokogiri?

Comment: Maybe they do that because they don't want people spidering their site with robots? You'd do well to read their terms-of-service for use of their site. Violating them can get you banned, and possible legal action.